# PHP move_uploaded_file Won't Work

Tags: php, ios

I have searched around google and none of the answers I have found are helping me. I am trying to use the function move_uploaded_file in php, and all I get these errors:

```
Notice: Undefined index: file in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/photos.php on line 53

Notice: Undefined index: file in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/photos.php on line 57
```

when I use this code:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if (!empty($_POST['firstName']) ) {
$firstname = htmlentities($_POST['firstName']);
echo $firstName;
} elseif (isset($_POST['lastName']) ) {
$lastname = htmlentities($_POST['lastName']);
echo $lastName;
}
if (isset($_POST['userId']) ) {
$userID = htmlentities($_POST['userId']);

echo $userId;
}



$target_dir = "wp-content/uploads/2015/02";
if(!file_exists($target_dir))
{
//chdir($target_dir);
mkdir($target_dir, 0777, true);
}







$target_dir = $target_dir . "/" . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);



$moveResult =  (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir)) ;

if ($moveResult == true) {

echo json_encode([
"Message" => "The file ". basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.",
"Status" => "OK",
"userId" => $_REQUEST["userId"]
]);

} else {
  if (isset($_REQUEST['userId']) ) {
  $user = $_REQUEST['userId'];
  }
echo json_encode([
//  echo filename;
"Message" => "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.",
"Status" => "Error",

//"userId" => $user,
]);


}





?>
```

or I get it to always return false when I use this code :

```
<?php

if (!empty($_POST['firstName']) ) {
$firstname = htmlentities($_POST['firstName']);
echo $firstName;
} elseif (isset($_POST['lastName']) ) {
$lastname = htmlentities($_POST['lastName']);
echo $lastName;
}
if (isset($_POST['userId']) ) {
$userID = htmlentities($_POST['userId']);

echo $userId;
}



$target_dir = "wp-content/uploads/2015/02";
if(!file_exists($target_dir))
{

mkdir($target_dir, 0777, true);
}





$target_dir = $target_dir . "/" . basename("filename");



$moveResult =  (move_uploaded_file('filename', $target_dir)) ;

if ($moveResult == true) {

echo json_encode([
"Message" => "The file ". basename($_FILES["filename"]). " has been   uploaded.",
"Status" => "OK",
"userId" => $_REQUEST["userId"]
 ]);

  } else {
  if (isset($_REQUEST['userId']) ) {
  $user = $_REQUEST['userId'];
  }
echo json_encode([
//  echo filename;
"Message" => "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.",
"Status" => "Error",

//"userId" => $user,
]);


}


?>
```

PS I have tried putting the code it would display my errors, but it doesn't report anything.

I am using this to make a server for my iOS app, and here is my swift code:

```
import UIKit

class photogetupload: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {



    @IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var myActivityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    @IBAction func uploadButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

        myImageUploadRequest()

    }

    @IBAction func selectPhotoButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

        var myPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        myPickerController.delegate = self;
        myPickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary

        self.presentViewController(myPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject])

    {
        myImageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    }

    func myImageUploadRequest()
    {

        let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:490/photos.php");
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST";

        let param = [
            "firstName" : "Nathan",
            "lastName" : "Huns",
            "userId" : "9"
        ]

        let boundary = generateBoundaryString()

        request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImageView.image, 1)

        if(imageData==nil) { return; }

        request.HTTPBody = createBodyWithParameters(param, filePathKey: "file", imageDataKey: imageData, boundary: boundary)

        myActivityIndicator.startAnimating();

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            data, response, error in

            if error != nil {
                println("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            // You can print out response object
            println("******* response = \(response)")

            // Print out reponse body
            let responseString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            println("****** response data = \(responseString!)")

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                self.myActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                self.myImageView.image = nil;
            });

        }

        task.resume()

    }

    func createBodyWithParameters(parameters: [String: String]?, filePathKey: String?, imageDataKey: NSData, boundary: String) -> NSData {

        var body = NSMutableData();

        if parameters != nil {
            for (key, value) in parameters! {
                body.appendString("–-\(boundary)\r\n")
                body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
                body.appendString("\(value)\r\n")
            }
        }

        let filename = "user--profile.jpg"

        let mimetype = "image/jpg"

        body.appendString("–-\(boundary)\r\n")
        body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(filePathKey!)\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n")
        body.appendString("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")
        body.appendData(imageDataKey)
        body.appendString("\r\n")

        body.appendString("–-\(boundary)–-\r\n")

        return body
    }

    func generateBoundaryString() -> String {
        return "Boundary-\(NSUUID().UUIDString)"
    }

}

extension NSMutableData {
    func appendString(string: String) {
        let data = string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
        appendData(data!)
    }
}
```

I don't get any errors, and here is what it logs

```
******* response = <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7f8f485a8e60> { URL: http://localhost:490/photos.php } { status code: 200, headers {
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Length" = 77;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Wed, 01 Jul 2015 16:54:31 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5, max=100";
    Server = "Apache/2.4.12 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1m PHP/5.6.8 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3";
    "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.6.8";
} }
****** response data = {"Message":"Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.","Status":"Error"}
```

Any solutions?
Thanks!

Comment: can you provide the html-form? the notice means that $_FILES['file'] is not set.

Comment: Please show your html form code. and are you using `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your html form?

Comment: in the form tag is there a attribute like: `enctype="multipart/form-data"`?

Comment: I'm trying to use this server for an iOS app and am using swift. Also, I have tried checking for $_FILES["file"] isset and it returns false, even though I'm positive it is set and that I'm posting the file!

Comment: And yes I am using "multiparty/form-data" in my app

Comment: @nathanHunsberger multiparty or multipart? would you like to show your html code too..!!

Comment: Sorry multipart, it was a typo

Comment: And I just posted my swift code

Comment: @AsifMushtaq I'm using it for a swift iOS app

Comment: @nathanHunsberger Always show complete detail, we was expecting it for HTML. you should use iOS related text in your title next time.

Comment: Sorry I'm a kinda newbie to programming

Answer (score 0):

```
* First of all make sure that your folder is having permission for read and write 
* Secondly input type="file" name="file" size="50 
check size of input and change it accordingly.
```

Your code is working just make sure above two points

```
<head>

    <title>A simple example of uploading a file using PHP script</title>

</head>

<body>

    <b>Simple example of uploading a file</b><br />

    Choose a file to be uploaded<br />

    <form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <input type="file" name="file" size="500" />

        <br />

        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />

    </form>

</body>
```

Now in upload_file.php make sure $target_dir having correct folder path to upload file

```
enter code here
    <?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if (!empty($_POST['firstName'])) {
    $firstname = htmlentities($_POST['firstName']);
    echo $firstName;
} elseif (isset($_POST['lastName'])) {
    $lastname = htmlentities($_POST['lastName']);
    echo $lastName;
}
if (isset($_POST['userId'])) {
    $userID = htmlentities($_POST['userId']);

    echo $userId;
}

$target_dir = "C:/xampp/htdocs/test/";
if (!file_exists($target_dir)) {
//chdir($target_dir);
    mkdir($target_dir, 0777, true);
}

$target_dir = $target_dir . "/" . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

$moveResult = (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir));

if ($moveResult == true) {

    echo json_encode([
        "Message" => "The file " . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]) . " has been uploaded.",
        "Status" => "OK",
        "userId" => $_REQUEST["userId"]
    ]);
} else {
    if (isset($_REQUEST['userId'])) {
        $user = $_REQUEST['userId'];
    }
    echo json_encode([
//  echo filename;
        "Message" => "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.",
        "Status" => "Error",
//"userId" => $user,
    ]);
}
?>
```

Comment: I get this <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: file in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/photos.php</b> on line <b>50</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: file in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/photos.php</b> on line <b>52</b><br />
{"Message":"Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.","Status":"Error"}

Comment: and this in browser Notice: Undefined index: file in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/photos.php on line 50

Notice: Undefined index: file in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/photos.php on line 52